# Loop through used cells in the reverse order

Tags: vba, loops, reverse

I was trying to delete my unwanted columns in the ACTIVE sheet using the below code :

```
Sub DeleteUnwantedColumns()
Dim LastUsedCell As Integer
Dim deleteRange As Range
LastUsedCell = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.count
Set deleteRange = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(1, LastUsedCell))
arr = Array("FY17", "FY18", "FY19", "FY20", "FY21")
    For Each cell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(1, LastUsedCell))
        If IsError(Application.Match(cell.Value, arr, 0)) Then
             ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

with this code sheets are deleting which is not mentioned in the Array, but if i am deleting the column 2 then column 3 will be the column 2, so in that case the code is skipping the column 2 if the value is something else in the column 2.

is there any way to work this code from last usedcolumn to first column.
i tried with step-1 , but it showing an error in the code itself.

any help is appreciated.

Thank you in Advance

Comment: `Step -1` only works for indexed loops, not `For Each` loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a for loop and go backwards from usedRange.Columns.Count with Step -1.  You never used DeleteRange so I removed it.

```
Sub DeleteUnwantedColumns()
    
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim c As Integer
    
    arr = Array("FY17", "FY18", "FY19", "FY20", "FY21")
        
    For c = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
        If IsError(Application.Match(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, c), arr, 0)) Then
            ActiveSheet.Columns(c).Delete
            End If
        Next
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Chris Strickland

Comment: you're very welcome.  If this helped you please select it as the answer.